# Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Incorrect argument label in call (have 'fromViewController:content:delegate:', expected 'viewController:content:delegate

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have the following error in a project I'm running on my Mac:

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode):

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'fromViewController:content:delegate:', expected 'viewController:content:delegate:')
> /Users/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_social_content_share-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterSocialContentSharePlugin.swift:109:45

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

I've already made changes to Flutter and packages versions.

I currently have the following versions:

flutter: 3.7.3
dart: 2.19.2
DevTools: 2.20.1
flutter_social_content_share: ^1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself tells you what is wrong. The first parameter label in your function call is supposed to be `viewController:`, but you have `fromViewController:`. Simply change the first parameter of your function call from `fromViewController:` to `viewController:`.